# How to implement Array in python Swig.?

Tags: python, c++, arrays, opencv, swig

I am wrote sample C++ application. Now I am going communicate with Python through Swig.

**What I did**

1. Generated interface file for my function

**classify.i**

```
%module example

%{
#include "Facdetect.h"
%}
%include "typemaps.i"
%include "cstring.i"
%include "cdata.i"
%include <std_string.i>
%apply unsigned char *{unsigned char *x};
%apply double *INOUT{double *y};
%include "Facdetect.h"
```

**Facdetect.h**

```
#include <iostream>
class facedetect
{
public:
void display(unsigned char  *x,double  *y);
};
```

**sample.cpp**

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include "Facdetect.h"


using namespace std;
void facedetect::display( unsigned char  *x,double  *y)
{

    cv::Mat in(512,512,CV_8UC3,x);
    cv::Mat res=imdecode(in,1);

    cv::cvtColor(res,res,cv::COLOR_RGB2GRAY);

       std::vector<uchar> buff;
      cv::imencode(".jpg",res,buff);
       int k=0;
   std::cout<<" buffer size "<<buff.size()<<std::endl;
   for(int j=0;j<10;j++)
   {
   y[k++]=j;

   }
   }
```

**sample.py**

```
import os
import io
import sys
import time
import example
from PIL import Image
import struct
from array import array

def readimage(path):
    count = os.stat(path).st_size / 2
    with open(path, "rb") as f:
        return bytearray(f.read())

bytes = readimage("sample.jpg")
print len(bytes)
c=example.facedetect()
ret = array(10)
ret=c.display(bytes,ret)
print ret
```

1. I had successfully passed byte array from Python to C++.
2. Now i am passing double array values into python fro C++.
3. I did not get double array values in python from C++.

**What I need:**

1. How to get double array values from C++ to python.?
2. Is any **typemaps** i missed for generating **swig wrapper**.?